# Ajax call function with parameter / unlike and like Article

Tags: ajax, symfony

I want to like or unlike a Article. I have a Entity ArticleLike.
To register the "like" i call this function in my  ajax :

```
url : '{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id, 'like' : 1}) }}'
```

But the property 'like' is **1** when i **like** and **0** when i **unlike**

I want to have 2 button to call this ajax function and send 0 or 1 to ajax function depend on the button call

```
$(document).on('click', '#ajax', function(){  
  that = $(this);
  $.ajax({
       url : '{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id, 'like' : 1}) }}',
       type : 'POST',
       dataType : 'html',
       success : function(code_html, statut){ 
         code = JSON.parse(code_html);
         $("a.likeChange").html(code.likes);
         console.log(code_html)
     },
       error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it's bad practice to insert twig variables or functions within the javascript. What you can do is add data properties to your buttons:

```
<button data-url="{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id, 'like' : 1}) }}">Like</button>
```

and 0 for the other one. Then in your ajax you can get the url:

```
let url = $(this).data('url');
```

Comment: I find undefined in my consol when i do this :   `let url = $(this).data('url');
  console.log(url)`. and button `<a id="ajax" data-url="{{ path('post_like', {'id' : article.id, 'like' : 1}) }}" class="btn" role="button"></a>`

Comment: Can you replicate it? Works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/matrixatp/38qsdrmc/)

Comment: Sorry i do somethink bad.. i call the wrong function. So what u do work well ty